# Is there a way to query Azure Storage table using a column name which is not the partition key?

Tags: azure-table-storage

I've tried to query an azure table using a column name, but no data was returned after the execution. Following is the code I used in java. Does a table scan is needed?

```
String partitionFilter = TableQuery.generateFilterCondition(
            COLUMN_ID,
            TableQuery.QueryComparisons.EQUAL,
            columnId);
```

Comment: Such a filter will definitely result in a table scan since no partition key is specified. Regarding no data returned issue, please provide more code context and what's the definition of const COLUMN_ID, since we are not able to help you via just one line of code.

Comment: It will end up in entire table scan as Zhaoxing commented. Generally speaking if this is a common scenario you could denormalize  your data and create new rows where the property you query is part of the PK or RK. Alternatively I would consider Azure Cosmos db which indexes all properties hence no penalty on querying a property.

Comment: Hey, the table storage is designed to have bulk amount of data. Don't be shy to have different tables referencing the same record. I strongly suggest, to create different tables using for each one, one of the column to be filtered as partition key. Modify your logic to perform a query to all the tables in parallel and join the results in your logic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Does a table scan is needed?

Yes, it performs a table scan, because your filter does not include the PartitionKey. Please refer to "[Design for querying](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/storage-table-design-guide#design-for-querying)" section to get detailed information.

> no data was returned after the execution

Please check whether some data in your table storage can meet the Filter condition. Besides, you can use HTTP(S) traffic capture tool (such as fiddler) to capture the request and check whether any error or useful information included in the response, which will help you troubleshoot the issue.

**Update:**

> Is there a way to index the column name, so that the query is more efficient?

Currently, there are no indexes other than that on the clustered index on the PartitionKey and RowKey in Azure table storage. If possible, you can modify your [table design](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/storage-table-design-guide#table-design-patterns) to improve performance. Besides, you can also move to [Azure Cosmos DB's "premium table"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/table-introduction) that offers throughput-optimized tables, global distribution, and automatic secondary indexes.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. As per my understanding, to generate a table scan, we have to use the partition key. In my scenario, partition key and row key are already been assigned to 2 columns, and we can't change that. Also this method does not accept partition key or row key as parameters. So we have to use only the specific column name (which is not PK or RK) to query the table

Comment: If you check [the link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/storage-table-design-guide#design-for-querying) that I provided, you can find the concept of Point Query, Range Query, Partition Scan and **Table Scan** ( not include the PartitionKey and is very inefficient).

Comment: yes it's very inefficient since it performs a full table scan. Is there a way to index the column name, so that the query is more efficient?

Comment: There are no indexes other than that on the clustered index on the PartitionKey and RowKey.